# Unexpected behaviour of array on negative index

Tags: c++

Below mention is my code. Please explain me why on negative index of array the IDE are printing either the garbage value or `0`,instead of segmentation fault as we cannot access the negative indices in the array.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;

int main() {
   int n=10;
   int i=1;

   vector<int> arr(n,-1);
   // arr[i-2]=0;
   cout<<arr[i-2]<<endl;
   
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's undefined behavior. Anything can happen. And anything can be garbage values, 0, a segmentation fault or ordering pizza over the Internet. Unfortunately, by experiment I find that the latter is so unlikely that you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: More precisely, accessing the negative indices in the array is an Undefined Behavior.

Comment: C++ says this is [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) not a segmentation fault.

Comment: There's no array in your code. You're calling `operator[]` of `std::vector`, which takes a `std::size_t` as parameter. So your `(int)-1` gets cast to `std::size_t` resulting in the maximum representable `std::size_t`, which is greater than `10`, hence out of bounds.

Comment: You have been misled if you think that C++ will behave predictably when you have bugs in your program. Most of the time when you break the C++ rules the behaviour of your entire program becomes undefined.

Comment: I spent 20 minutes of my life writing an in-depth answer to this question, just to realize it has been closed :)

Answer (score 1):

A *segmentation fault* occurs in C++ when your program attempts to access memory **not** within the memory that the operating system allocated for your program. In other words, accessing memory that isn't yours.

According to [the documentation for `std::vector::operator[]`](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/operator%5B%5D/), under "Exception Safety", when accessing an index that is out of bounds, "the behavior is undefined". This means no checks are done.

Does this mean that a *segmentation fault* techically can occur? Yes. As the behaviour is undefined, it may just be that you are accessing memory that isn't yours, and a *segmentation fault* is signalled. As the behaviour is undefined, it might just be that the address you are trying to read is allocated to your program and can store `0`, garbage, or any other value.

In practice, an error generally will not be thrown if you're trying to access the `[-1]` index of a vector or array, or if you go out of bounds. This is why a variety of undefined behaviour sanitizers, such as [one made for Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html), are available to you. Upon undefined behaviour, these will raise an error and terminate your program.

Comment: When you access `[-1]` on a `std::vector`, you most likely go out of bounds by a very large amount.

Comment: Oh right, its an unsigned value... oops.